# How can I add phone authentication in firebase using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

So firebase recently supported phone auth, but the problem is that the documentation is in objective-c. And I have never done push notifications before. this is a link to the objc phone auth docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth

Comment: I can see where, if you are not familiar with both Swift and ObJ it would be a little challenging ;-).  I think they may still working on the documentation. Send and email to support@firebase.com in case they... 'overlooked' adding Swift code examples.

Comment: Swift snippets in the docs are on the way! Still catching up on this kind of thing post-Google I/O :)

Answer (score 3):

You can see an example in the official sample repo: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/authentication/AuthenticationExampleSwift/MainViewController.swift#L161

The core process is like this:

```
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) { (verificationID, error) in
    if let error = error {
      // TODO: show error
      return
    }
    guard let verificationID = verificationID else { return }
    verificationCode = // TODO: get SMS verification code from user.
    if let verificationCode = verificationCode {
      let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationID, verificationCode: verificationCode)
      Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
        // TODO: handle sign in
      }
    } else {
      // Verification code was empty
    }
  }
}
```

You'll need to plug in UI to prompt the user (thats in the sample), or take advantage of FirebaseUI to handle it all for you: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS

Comment: I am using the default `FirebaseUI`. After phone number authentication is verified the delegate method is not called `func authUI(_ authUI: FIRAuthUI, didSignInWith user: FIRUser?, error: Error?) ` . Should I attach a `addStateDidChangeListener` in the controller where I present `FUIAuth?` ViewController and detach it later in viewDidDissaper or what is the flow? I did read the docks, btw.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52821746