# How do I bypass the welcome screen UI and present only the phone auth UI screen in Firebase Auth?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

How can I present the viewController which is responsible for collecting phone number data in FirebaseUI rather than the welcome screen?

With the current set up I am presented with a Welcome screen.

```
   class Login: UIViewController, FUIAuthDelegate {
    let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()

     override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


    let phoneProvider = FUIPhoneAuth(authUI: authUI!)
    authUI!.isSignInWithEmailHidden = true
    authUI!.providers = [phoneProvider]
    let vc = authUI?.authViewController()

    self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
 }
```

**EDIT**
Thanks to proxpero I can present the phone UI like this:

```
class Login: UIViewController, FUIAuthDelegate {
    let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()

   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    authUI?.delegate = self
    let phoneProvider = FUIPhoneAuth(authUI: authUI!)
    authUI!.isSignInWithEmailHidden = true
    authUI!.providers = [phoneProvider]
    phoneProvider.signIn(withPresenting: self, phoneNumber: nil)
     }
 }
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bypass the welcome screen, and present the phone auth screen straightaway, I think that instead of `self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)`, put `phoneProvider.signIn(withPresenting: self, phoneNumber: nil)`.

This method on `phoneProvider` creates the phone auth ui view controller and presents it on the parent view controller that you pass in (`self` in this case).